# Problem configuring WebP Express WordPress plugin on nginx

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to configure the WebP Express plugin for WordPress for an nginx server. I'm following these excellent guidelines: https://wordpress.org/plugins/webp-express/#i%20am%20on%20nginx%20or%20openresty. It says there:
"So for this to work, you must configure WebP Express to store the converted files like that by setting General > File extension to Append “.webp”."
My problem is that this is grayed out (disabled) - I cannot select an option. It may well be, though, that ' Append “.webp”' is already selected (it's what's showing, just grayed out) and I just can't change it, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the destination folder to Mingled for the file extension to be editable.